# Linker warnings xcode 7.1

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, swift

I'm using a third-party library and my app is working perfectly but I have strange warning errors when building the app in xcode 7.1 :

```
ld: warning: direct access in boost::this_thread::interruption_point() to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::thread_interrupted means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::this_thread::interruption_point() to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::thread_interrupted means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::system::error_code::operator void (*)()() const to global weak symbol boost::system::error_code::unspecified_bool_true() means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::system::error_code::operator void (*)()() const to global weak symbol boost::system::error_code::unspecified_bool_true() means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::thread_resource_error>(boost::thread_resource_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::thread_resource_error>(boost::thread_resource_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::lock_error>(boost::lock_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::lock_error>(boost::lock_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::detail::spinlock_pool<1>::spinlock_for(void const*) to global weak symbol boost::detail::spinlock_pool<1>::pool_ means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::detail::spinlock_pool<1>::spinlock_for(void const*) to global weak symbol boost::detail::spinlock_pool<1>::pool_ means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::date_time::microsec_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::universal_time() to global weak symbol boost::date_time::c_time::gmtime(long const*, tm*) means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::date_time::microsec_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::universal_time() to global weak symbol boost::date_time::c_time::gmtime(long const*, tm*) means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month>(boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month>(boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_day_of_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::gregorian::bad_month>(boost::gregorian::bad_month const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::gregorian::bad_month>(boost::gregorian::bad_month const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_month> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_month> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_month> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::gregorian::bad_year>(boost::gregorian::bad_year const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_year> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::gregorian::bad_year>(boost::gregorian::bad_year const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_year> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_year> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_year> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_year> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::gregorian::bad_year> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::condition_error>(boost::condition_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::condition_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in void boost::throw_exception<boost::condition_error>(boost::condition_error const&) to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::condition_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::detail::interruption_checker::check_for_interruption() to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::thread_interrupted means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::detail::interruption_checker::check_for_interruption() to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::thread_interrupted means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::condition_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::condition_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::condition_error> >::rethrow() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::condition_error> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

I'm using those library :

- libstdc++.6.tbd
- libiconv.tbd
- libsqlite3.0.tbd
- libxml2.2.tbd

Please Note that i already tried those solutions without success :

1. Symbols hidden by default & Inline Methods Hidden to YES/NO
2. Changing C++ Standard Library to 'libstdc++
3. I tried all the other version & .dylib of the library above
4. Adding empty cpp file

Thank's in advance

Comment: Can you try Xcode 7.3? (you will need El Capitan)

Comment: I saw in many topic that EL Capitan have many bugs. any chance to remove those warnings on xcode 7.1 ?

Comment: I installed Xcode 7.3 still the same warning. any solution ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample project with the issue?